# Is separate boostrap js plugin file is required?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap in my project and i am a beginner for bootstrap. I want to know that if i downloaded **bootstrap.js** and **bootstrap.css** and after that i want to use bootsrap js plugin like **carousel**, **popover** etc then i have to download a separate js file for each plugin or not ?

And if yes than is there any way to download a single **bootstrap.js** which cover all js plugins and boostrap.css which cover all js plugin css ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do that either way

the generic `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap.css` contains the entire bootstrap tools and widgets

Alternativly, you could create your own bootstrap with only the things you need on 
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html

and yes there is a way - http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

2 lines of code and you got bootstrap

Comment: but when i was trying to use bootstrap file uploader without its js file and css file, its not working, why ?

Comment: which bootstrap file uploader?

Comment: if you mean http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#fileupload that is an extension to twitter bootstrap (the original bootstrap). jasny's bootstrap is a customization and extension that must have twitter bootstrap in order to work

Comment: means for these extensions separate js and css files are needed ??

Comment: not seperate css and js - the original css and js. You can't use an extension of bootstrap without bootstrap itself... beyond twitter bootstrap, any extension needs to be added. So if you want file upload to work properly, you need to include the original files + the extension you want

Answer (score 0):

```
Plugins can be included individually (using Bootstrap's individual *.js
files, or all at once (using bootstrap.js or the minified bootstrap.min.js.
```

bootstrap.js includes them all. Why don't you check inside the file for its content?

Comment: but when i was trying to use bootstrap file uploader without its js file and css file, its not working, why ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't to download separate js file for each plugin. bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css are common files for all plugins.

Comment: but when i was trying to use bootstrap file uploader without its js file and css file, its not working, why ?